# How to block public access to specific endpoint in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, security, spring-boot-actuator, aws-security-group

We want to secure spring-boot actuator endpoints inside aws.  Requirement is not to use spring boot application.yml properties provided by spring boot and secure them using just aws and vpc an/or loadbalancer configuration.

For example
/actuator/* endpoints

Comment: [How to block loadbalancer forwarding to a specific path?](https://serverfault.com/questions/867745/how-to-block-loadbalancer-forwarding-to-a-specific-path)

Comment: Thanks for your response. @luk2302 How can we allow internal users to access those endpoints who're coming from vpn?